# How to make any bitmap in cylinder shape just like image added to any mug in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

`[image]

There is an requirement in my project to set any bitmap into mug and also edit bitmap and wright some text on image then past this bitmap to mug just like attached image .

I need a solution in Android or any supported library, Before I have tried to do this with Android  Canvas and its method to draw arc But not reached my requirement.

```
/**
 * Draw one image over other using the canvas paint and path drawing.
 */
public Bitmap createMaskedImageInImageCenterRightMug(Drawable back,
                                                     Bitmap bitmapToDrawInTheCenter) {

    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) back).getBitmap();
    int hieghtBack = backgroundBitmap.getHeight();
    int widthBack = backgroundBitmap.getWidth();
    int hieghtFront = bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.getHeight();
    int widthFront = bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.getWidth();
    int widthToDrawOnMug = widthBack / 2;
    backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundBitmap, (int) canvas_width, hieghtBack, true);
    // Create mask
    Bitmap backgroundBitmapMask = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 7, 0, (int) (canvas_width / 2), hieghtBack);
    if (widthToDrawOnMug <= widthFront) {
        bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, (widthFront * 40) / 100, 0,
                (widthFront * 60) / 100, hieghtFront);
    }
    Bitmap backgroundBitmapScaledMask = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            backgroundBitmapMask, widthToDrawOnMug, hieghtBack - 50, true);

    bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, backgroundBitmapScaledMask.getWidth(),
            backgroundBitmapScaledMask.getHeight(), true);
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            backgroundBitmapScaledMask.getWidth(),
            backgroundBitmapScaledMask.getHeight(),
            backgroundBitmapScaledMask.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmapScaledMask, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 0, 0, paint);
    return resultBitmap;
}

/**
 * Draw one image over other using the canvas paint and path drawing.
 */
public Bitmap pasteOverMugForRightMug(Drawable back,
                                      Bitmap bitmapToDrawInTheCenter) {
    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) back).getBitmap();
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap.getWidth(), backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), backgroundBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, 0, 25, paint);
    return resultBitmap;
}
```

Here is my code . Some hard code values are used according plain Mug image Aspect Ratio.
Also Tried to do this with Open GL but it was very complex .
And  and could not find  method for cylinder shape in  one of the image processing library Image magic.

if any one have an idea please share .

Comment: can you post your try atleast?

Comment: "Before I have tried to do this with Android Canvas and its method to draw arc"  means you haven't event tried ?? o_O

Comment: Please check i puted my core code to process input image without having cylinder shape.

Comment: Try imagemagick cylinder distortion

Comment: Already Tried with - cylinder distortion in Image Magic

Comment: @Chetan did you found solution for this?

Comment: we have alternative solution with some limitation but not match actual requirement according above image.

Comment: @selva_pollachi have you find any solution .

Comment: @Chetan actually i am also looking for solution. can you please help  me?

Comment: You can use above code to to this but is Working in 80 % cases .